# Set a name for each ImageSource in a list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, imagesource

I call an API and get from there an id, a name and an URL for images...

I display them in a flipview and I used to convert them, saved them in a folder, convert them back and show them...

So I thought it would be much easier if I show them directly from their URL.

Now, when the user clicks (taps) on the image, it has to go to another page to show the detail of that image (and it was working fine, when saving the pic, since I named them by the id (id.png))

is there anyway I can name the ImageSource to be this id, or give it like a property (Title or Name)?

```
var pics = from special in GlobalVariables.Special
           where special.special == "1"
           select new { id = special.id, name = special.name, image = special.banner_image, featured = special.special };

foreach (var item in pics)
{
   await savePicToDisk(item.image, item.name, item.id, item.featured);
}
```

So, then, instead of save them:

```
List<ImageSource> listOfImages = new List<ImageSource>();    

string url = "http://52.8.2.140" + picAddress;

ImageSource urlOfPic = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));

listOfImages.Add(urlOfPic);
```

Then, where I have to show them, I just bind it to the flipview:

```
flipView1.DataContext = Classes.Special.listOfImages;
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Item_Click* event's arguments have a property *ClickedItem* (in some cases you may also need *OriginalSource*), which you can use to point to your item in a collection. If item's class has a property responsible for Name/Id/other you can freely pass that when navigating, other solution may be passing an index of selected item in the collection. Sample code;

```cs
private void ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as ItemClass;
    if (item != null) 
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), item.ID);
    // if your item contains a Name/Id/other you can pass that when navigating
    // you can also pass index of your item in collection if you need
}
```